# Combining multiple rows into one entity in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I've been trying to grow my EF understanding from just querying tables to creating Entities that match my business objects so I can code against my business objects rather than my data objects.  I read articles that suggest this is possible, but all of their examples are rather trivial and involve just combining two tables.  My situation is a little more complicated and I'm not sure how to proceed.

I have two tables (simplified below)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BarEvents]
(
[BarGUID]       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),    
[Bar]               INT              NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BarLog]
(
[BarGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
[BarLogGUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
[BarEventTime] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE()
)
```

So if I join these tables, for a specific BarGUID, so if I had 1 Bar and 4 bar events logged, I'd have 4 rows, but what I want is just the most recent BarEventTime.  So I would like to join and have just one row:

I can do this trivially in EF:

```
var query = barEntities.BarEvents.Where( q=> q.BarGUID = '0000-0000-0000-0000')
    .Select(barEvent =>
    new LogItem()
    {
        Bar = barEvent.Bar,
        BarEventTime =     barEvent.BarLog.Max(u => u.BarEventTime)
    });
```

But from what I've read, I should be able to define a LogItem entity, and place this logic somehow in my LogItem entity, then write queries against that.  My problem is I only see trivial join conditions when I'm trying to join my tables in the entity definitions.  Is there a way to do this?  Or a guide?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the following:

- Create a `SQL View` in the Database that does what you want
- Add the view to your `EF Context`
- Use the newly created entity that is based on the view

Comment: That is one option.  I could also write a sproc to do this for me and then use the sproc in EF.  Or just stick with my current query.  I guess I had just hoped there was a way to accomplish this within the entity definition itself. EDIT: to clarify, our DBAs are locking down everything sql server side more every day, so avoiding sprocs/views was part of my goal in swapping to EF.